# Laravel: Array to string conversion while uploading .sql files

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

**Edit: It turns out this issue happens while trying to upload .sql files. It's not the file name.**

When I try to upload a file with this name: `forge_2016-02-08_--USERS THOUGH.sql` I'm shown this error below:

> ErrorException in FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php line 69:
>
> Array to string conversion

and

> at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Array to string conversion', '/home/forge/example.com/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php', '69', array('path' => '/tmp/phppkDGK8', 'finfo' => object(finfo)))
>
> at finfo->file('/tmp/phppkDGK8') in FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php line 69
>
> at finfo->file('/tmp/phppkDGK8') in FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php line 69
>   at FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser->guess('/tmp/phppkDGK8') in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 139

I have no idea why this error is happening. Here's my upload code:

```
    $baseDir = storage_path('uploads');

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
    $name = str_random(6) . time() . '-' . str_replace(' ', '_', Str::ascii($file->getClientOriginalName()));
    $file->move($baseDir, $name);

    $path = $baseDir . '/' . $name;
    $data = ['path' => $path, 'ip' => userIP(), 'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'mime' => $mimeType, 'size' => $file->getClientSize()];
    $status = Uploads::create($data);

    if ($status) {
          $su = true;
```

Please help guys. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Do you really want to follow the `$name` convention you used?

Comment: @JilsonThomas yes, why? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I doubt if the error is there. Can you try to `dd('ok');` before and after the $name creation? Just to see where is the error. ?

Comment: The error is at `$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();`

Comment: Can you check if $request->file('file')->isValid() ?

Comment: I've fixed it by getting rid of getMimeType in general. Couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing

```
$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
```

to

```
$mimeType = $file->getClientMimeType();
```

This fixed it.

Comment: The method name `getClientMimeType` sounds like this will only get you the MIME type the client sent – which can be dangerous, as it could possibly allow someone to upload files of a type you _don’t_ want, by simply faking the MIME type. So this is definitively _not_ what I’d call a “fix” of the issue.

Comment: Using the `getMimeType` shows array to string conversion error if the file is an sql file or has no extension at all. The files they uploaded are stored in the storage folder. If I'm allowing them to upload any type of file, and I simply store it in the storage folder and not run it, how is it dangerous to me? I'm simply curious. Thanks.

Comment: So you would even allow the user to upload `.php` files? By the looks of it it seems you keep the original file extension – so if those uploads go into a directory where they are reachable via HTTP and PHP code gets parsed in files ending with `.php` as usual, a user could upload and execute _any_ arbitrary PHP code they like …

Comment: The uploaded files are stored in the storage folder which cannot be accessed via HTTP. Is that safe?